# NodeJS: Issue with handling file uploading

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I did not know what to write as the title, as I am having a very strange issue. What I am trying to do is upload and save *.html files on server. Following is the code structure:

**Jade Template (Form):**

```
#template-uploader
    form(enctype='multipart/form-data')
        input(name='file', type='file')
        input#upload-template(type='button', value='Upload')
```

**JS (Form Handle):**

```
//Upload Btn Click Event Handler
$('#upload-template').on('click', function(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    uploadFiles();
});

// Upload the files using AJAX
function uploadFiles()
{
    var formData = $('input[type=file]')[0].files;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'template/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){
                // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        data: formData[0],
        cache: false,
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log('Data');
            console.log(data);
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                // Success so call function to process the form
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + errorThrown);
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
}
```

**Server (Node.js)**

```
//Route handler for template file uploaded
router.post('/template/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Uploading Files');
    console.log(req.files);
});
```

Now the issue is that when I select a file and click the upload button, an ajax request is made. I have logged the data that I am sending and seems good at the client end. On server side there are however two issues.

1. (Issue solved by answer from @Scimonster)I don't see any file in `req.files` param. I did this before in Express 3.x without any issues. Now I am using Express 4.x, and maybe I am missing something.
2. The second issue is that when the request is sent to server, the terminal immediately logs the `console.log('Uploading Files')` message. But I don't receive any error or success message on client side. I also don't see in terminal that a POST request was received for the mentioned route. However after 2 minutes (every time), the terminal logs the request received for the route including the `console.log()` message. And this is when I get a response on client side.

**Terminal Logging:**

```
Uploading Files
undefined
POST /dashboard/template/upload 200 **120004ms**
Uploading Files
undefined
```

This is beyond me. I don't think there are any pre-flight checks generated by client side.If someone can provide insight as to what might the issue be, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.files`  from Express 3 is from the body parser middleware. In 4.x, this is no longer packaged with Express. You can install [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme) and include it as explained in the docs to enable `req.files`.

Comment: Thanks. I am receiving the files now using `multer`. That solves my first issue. I am upvoting you for that. I will mark an answer after I find the solution for second part also.

Comment: It looks like you're not explicitly returning to the user - use res.send("stuff") for that.